# Function in Netlogo

Tags: function, netlogo

Can anyone explain what this function does?

```
to active_social_distancing
  ask turtles [set my_move 0.2] ; the distance a person can make is reduced to 0.2 definitely
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a user-defined procedure that asks each turtle to set a turtles-own variable, `my-move`, to 0.2.  Without the rest of the code, we don't know how `my-move` is used by each turtle, but it presumably is determining how far a turtle can move, or perhaps how far it must stay from another turtle.

It's not unusual to have a procedure that simply sets a variable as it takes that action out of the middle of a larger segment of code and puts it where it can easily be found, and changed.

Charles

Comment: Thanks I found that my_move is how much forward a turtle goes each tick so for example if social distancing is put to active it moves forward 0.2 every tick and if it is not active it moves forward 3 every tick. Thanks for answering!